# 'RTLD_NEXT' undeclared

Tags: c, linux, include, cygwin, undefined

I'm trying to compile a C program but I get the error 'RTLD_NEXT' undeclared.  I think this is supposed to be defined in dlfcn.h which the c program includes, but when I looked inside dlfcn.h there is no RTLD_NEXT.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You had better tell us exactly what Linux distro and gcc version if you are defining _GNU_SOURCE and not succeeding.

Comment: @bmargulies: he's using cygwin (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777523/how-to-make-this-c-program-compile/1777566#1777566 ), which does not support `RTLD_NEXT` (see eg http://lists.zerezo.com/cygwin/msg38882.html )

Answer (score 40):

The issue here is that `RTLD_NEXT` is not defined by the [posix standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) . So the GNU people don't enable it unless you `#define _GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_GNU_SOURCE`.

Other relevant pieces of POSIX are [dlfcn.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dlfcn.h.html) and [dlsym.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html#tag_03_112_07). Interestingly, the later mentions `RTLD_NEXT`. Apparently, the GNU people are a bit confused about what is an extension and what is not.

Comment: better link to http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dlfcn.h.html and http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html#tag_03_112_07

Answer (score 10):

According to `man dlsym` it is `#define _GNU_SOURCE` (just one leading underscore) *before* the `dlfcn.h` is included. (RHEL6.1).

Answer (score 4):

Try `#define __GNU_SOURCE` as first line in your sources.

Comment: It's actually `__USE_GNU`, just noting since this is the top Google result for "RTLD_NEXT" now.

Comment: It is just *one* leading underscore: `#define _GNU_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 3):

There must be one underscore. `#define _GNU_SOURCE`
Further, this must be your first preprocessor directive.For example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: yes, first directive of *all* directives. This should be the accepted answer