# How to make this C program compile?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

When I type gcc gprof-helper.c to compile the program I get these errors:

```
gprof-helper.c: In function `wooinit':
gprof-helper.c:38: error: `RTLD_NEXT' undeclared (first use in this function)
gprof-helper.c:38: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
gprof-helper.c:38: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

This is the program file:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void * wrapper_routine(void *);

/* Original pthread function */
static int (*pthread_create_orig)(pthread_t *__restrict,
                                  __const pthread_attr_t *__restrict,
                                  void *(*)(void *),
                                  void *__restrict) = NULL;

/* Library initialization function */
void wooinit(void) __attribute__((constructor));

void wooinit(void)
{
    pthread_create_orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
    fprintf(stderr, "pthreads: using profiling hooks for gprof\n");
    if(pthread_create_orig == NULL)
    {
        char *error = dlerror();
        if(error == NULL)
        {
            error = "pthread_create is NULL";
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* Our data structure passed to the wrapper */
typedef struct wrapper_s
{
    void * (*start_routine)(void *);
    void * arg;

    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t  wait;

    struct itimerval itimer;

} wrapper_t;

/* The wrapper function in charge for setting the itimer value */
static void * wrapper_routine(void * data)
{
    /* Put user data in thread-local variables */
    void * (*start_routine)(void *) = ((wrapper_t*)data)->start_routine;
    void * arg = ((wrapper_t*)data)->arg;

    /* Set the profile timer value */
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &((wrapper_t*)data)->itimer, NULL);

    /* Tell the calling thread that we don't need its data anymore */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&((wrapper_t*)data)->lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&((wrapper_t*)data)->wait);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&((wrapper_t*)data)->lock);

    /* Call the real function */
    return start_routine(arg);
}

/* Our wrapper function for the real pthread_create() */
int pthread_create(pthread_t *__restrict thread,
                   __const pthread_attr_t *__restrict attr,
                   void * (*start_routine)(void *),
                   void *__restrict arg)
{
    wrapper_t wrapper_data;
    int i_return;

    /* Initialize the wrapper structure */
    wrapper_data.start_routine = start_routine;
    wrapper_data.arg = arg;
    getitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &wrapper_data.itimer);
    pthread_cond_init(&wrapper_data.wait, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&wrapper_data.lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&wrapper_data.lock);

    /* The real pthread_create call */
    i_return = pthread_create_orig(thread,
                                   attr,
                                   &wrapper_routine,
                                   &wrapper_data);

    /* If the thread was successfully spawned, wait for the data
     * to be released */
    if(i_return == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&wrapper_data.wait, &wrapper_data.lock);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wrapper_data.lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&wrapper_data.lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&wrapper_data.wait);

    return i_return;
}
```

How do I get rid of those errors?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777397/rtldnext-undeclared

Comment: Also, see http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html (more details about the issue)

Comment: I thought that if I included the whole program file I would get better answers.

Comment: So why didn't you just add the extra detail of the "program file" to the original question that you asked an hour ago? Why start a completely new question?

Comment: @Phenom: posting the entire source will include much extraneous code. Better to post a minimal test case: just enough code to demonstrate the problem and no more.

Comment: I was thinking maybe someone would try to run it and then fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RTLD_NEXT` has been available in glibc since time immemorial.
Are you building on a Linux (or glibc-based) system? Doesn't sound like it.

Update:
`RTLD_NEXT` is a `glibc` *extension*. You can't use it on `cygwin`, because `cygwin` != `glibc`.
As far as I understand, `cygwin` doesn't support `LD_PRELOAD` either, so even if you succeeded in building this library, it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @Phenom: you should have said that earlier; cygwin doesn't support `RTLD_NEXT` (see eg this message http://lists.zerezo.com/cygwin/msg38882.html from october 2008)