# Symbol 'RTLD_NEXT' could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse, file, overriding, fopen

Working on a project and I need to override fopen() function.I call it to another .c file including what is required and making a true makefile with setting LD_PRELOAD.In Eclipse IDE I have 2 errors "Symbol 'RTLD_NEXT' could not be resolved    ".When I run it manually from terminal I dont get any error but seems like this fopen() doesn't replace the original. I prove this when I call a printf(" ") in my fopen() and don't see the result.

```
logger: logger.c
    gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o logger.so logger.c -lcrypto -ldl 

acmonitor: acmonitor.c 
    gcc acmonitor.c -o acmonitor

test_aclog: test_aclog.c 
    gcc test_aclog.c -o test_aclog

run: logger.so test_aclog
    LD_PRELOAD=./logger.so ./test_aclog

clean:
    rm -rf logger.so
    rm -rf test_aclog
    rm -rf acmonitor
```

```
fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{

    printf("In our own fopen, opening %s\n", path);
    FILE *original_fopen_ret;
    FILE *(*original_fopen)(const char*, const char*);

    /* call the original fopen function */
    original_fopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    original_fopen_ret = (*original_fopen)(path, mode);


    /* */
    /* ... */
    /* ... */
    /* ... */
    /* ... */


    return original_fopen_ret;
}
```

Comment: Did you [`#include <dlfcn.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html)?

Comment: edited the post. Yes i included

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777397/rtld-next-undeclared answer your question?

Comment: No it does not.